# Reload Activity when theme is changed from Dark to Light Them or vice versa

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-theme

I have an activity which is launched as new task, for which I want to call finish() in  onStop(in order to exclude it from recent apps list). But I noticed an error when theme is changed lets say from dark to light theme from the notification tray this activity gets closed automatically because there is finish() in onStop. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

use `recreate()` to restart an activity rather than an activity that launched as a new task.